# python broken after conda remove openssl

Tags: macos, python, openssl

While trying to resolve package dependency problems, I used conda to uninstall openssl, since this appeared to be one of the packages with unsatisfiable specifications. However, once I did this, everything broke:

conda became broken: any attempt to use conda results in "ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found"
iPython become broken: I get the same error message
pip is broken: again the same error message

I have tried brew install openssl, but this only returns a message that openssl is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried brew install openssl, but this only returns a message that openssl is already installed.

You should use the `--force` to force a installation.

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
```

Apparently, there's also a `reinstall` command:

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Also see [How do you re-install a package with Homebrew (Mac)?](https://superuser.com/q/324980/173513) on Super User.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the --force option or the reinstall command. I tried both, and each time brew returns an apparently successful reinstall of openssl. However, this does not resolve the issue: ipython, pip, and conda all still return the same error message.

Comment: @aph - sorry to hear it. Have you tried a reinstall of the other problem packages with `--force`? (Sorry, I don't really use Brew - I use MacPorts).

Comment: all packages actually seem to have the same problem. Once I uninstalled openssl, that alone triggered pip, conda, and iPython to break. For some reason, it must be that iPython looks for openssl in a different location than the place where brew installs it to.

Comment: @aph - You might be able to use [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) to spy on iPython's disk reads and writes. I use it on occasion for things like this. Otherwise, you might need to re-download [iPython](http://ipython.org/install.html), which may require you to re-install Python.